# Connecting to GAE using NetBeans

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java EE web application that I want to deploy to Google App Engine using the NetBeans GAE plugin. I go to Services>Servers>Add Server and select Google App Engine server, select the location of the GAE SDK. On the next screen, where I would enter the host address of the GAE server, the only option is localhost - clicking on it is disabled.

Is deploying to an actual GAE web server not supported by the plugin, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Your Application Name

Your application name is the name you chose for your application when you created your account at the Google App Engine website. To set the application name, follow these instructions:

1. Open the ./WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml file.
2. Set the application name to match the application name you set up at Google App Engine.

Deploy Your App

1. Right-click on your project in the Projects list
2. Select “Deploy To Google App Engine”
3. Fill in your Google Account credentials when prompted.